# SQL DELETE/UPDATE: удаление/обновление нескольких таблиц в один запрос

Tags: sqlite3, sql

Доброго времени суток!

Никак не могу найти ответа на этот вопрос: можно ли удалить запись сразу из нескольких таблиц? Ситуация такая: есть главная таблица и ещё несколько. Все они связаны через ключ:

```
главная.id = следующая1.id = следующая2.id = ...
```

Сработает ли такое удаление:

```
DELETE FROM главная, следующая1, следующая2, ...  
WHERE id = 26
```

Или нужно будет посылать отдельные DELETE-ы в каждую таблицу? (Если не использовать foreign key.)

Аналогичный вопрос относительно Update: необходимо обновить в этих таблицах список полей (имена полей соответственно для каждой таблицы свои). Можно ли собрать все эти таблицы JOIN-ом в одну и её обновить?

Что-то типа:

```
UPDATE Главная INNER JOIN следующая1 ON Главная.ID = Следующая1.ID
SET .....
```

Или вариант только один: обновлять каждую таблицу отдельно?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Данный вопрос обсуждался в данной ветке если не ошибаюсь
http://q-answer.ru/questions/sozdanie-kopii-bazy-dannyh-v-postgresql-14156.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы сделать удаление / обновление в разных таблицах, для внешних ключей следует задать каскадное удаление и обновление.

```
ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT 
FOREIGN KEY [...]
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Вы можете связать внешними ключами первичные ключи. Мы такую конструкцию активно используем для отображения наследования в БД.

Кроме того, если Вы всё-таки не можете использовать внешние ключи, Вы можете создать триггеры. Вы можете создать View на базе объединения таблиц, создать для неё INSTEAD OF-триггер для удаления / обновления и делать команду UPDATE / DELETE применительно ко View. В этом случае вызовется созданный триггер.

А одной командой - не получится.

Comment: Покопался в документации SQLite3 (а именно он используется) - он не поддерживает такое обновление ограничений (CONSTRAINT) для существующей таблицы. Задавать FOREIGN KEY можно только при создании таблицы. 
Причём не совсем понял насчёт связывания первичных ключей: вроде там написано, что в главной таблице нельзя, чтобы ключ был связан с RowId (надо использовать своё именованное поле), а у меня своё именованное поле, которое заменяет родной RowId - можно ли его использовать не разобрался.

Но идея ясна! Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю удалять (в соответствии с синтаксисом SQL)
можно только из одной таблицы.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp